# Why can't I offer a bounty on my 3 day old question?

Tags: support, bounties

I have 78 reputation and [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136537/rails-jquery-mobile-application-submitting-forms-and-gets-twice) is eligible for bounty 2 days ago. Yet I cannot offer a bounty on my question.

[image: Cannot offer a bounty]

It appears that because I have an answer on my question, the system requires me to offer a minimum bounty of 100. But since my answer is already deleted, what can I do to offer a bounty on my question now?

Answer (score 9):

> Previously the OP has 68 reputation so he cannot offer a bounty on his question. A further discussion reveals a different issue with the question where he wish to place a bounty and this answer is no longer relevant. I am keeping this answer here to retain discussion in the comments section.

You need to maintain [75 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to have the privilege to set a bounty, even though the minimum bounty amount is 50. The bounties [you have offered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951321/markhorrocks?tab=bounties&sort=offered) reduced your reputation below the privilege requirement.

> [image: bounty privilege]

Comment: I have 78 points but can't see any option to place a bounty.

Comment: @markhorrocks Can you give a link to the question where you wish to place a bounty?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136537/rails-jquery-mobile-application-submitting-forms-and-gets-twice

Comment: @markhorrocks Well, [I can see an option to start a bounty](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu9VE.png). Do you see it now? If not, can you take a screenshot of it?

Comment: [link]http://i41.tinypic.com/2m7hoiu.png [/link]

Comment: @markhorrocks That looks peculiar. What do you see when you click on it?

Comment: It linked to an info page about applying bounties.

Comment: Thanks, how to I set a flag for moderator attention?

Comment: @markhorrocks Wait, in your screenshot, is that a deleted answer of yours? If you have an answer for your question, the minimum bounty amount is 100.

Comment: Yes, I deleted an answer because it turned out to be false. The problem is intermittent so now I am stuck with a show stopper issue and no way to attract attention to it?

Comment: So now the issue is that: You have a deleted answer of yours in the question, but you cannot offer a bounty at 78 rep because the system assumes that the minimum bounty is 100 for questions with self-answers. Let me edit your question and flag it for you.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that.

Comment: In the very first section: “Note: If you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).”

Comment: @minitechη I know, and I have stated that in the comments above. But it looks like an unfortunate incident that the OP answered his own question, only to know it was not the right answer and deleted it afterwards, making him unable to place a bounty for 50 rep. It looks broken to me not be able to place a bounty because of a deleted self-answer. Of course it could lead to exploitation, but I wish some one would have some sympathy on the OP's situation and do something about it. I just wanted to help.

Comment: The question of why is a duplicate of the FAQ; the answer to “how” is just “it’s not possible”, unfortunately. Well, for @markhorrocks, anyways. I’ll get it =)

Comment: @minitechη That's some generosity right there. A declined flag isn't that bad after all.