# Why does the duplicate header not show up in the off-topic-close dialog?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

When voting to close, the duplicate header does not show up in the preview:

[image: Shows a (closed) question in the off-topic preview without the duplicate header.]

Steps to reproduce:

- Find a closed (as duplicate) question (f.e. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185127/why-cant-i-offer-a-bounty-on-my-3-day-old-question))
- Find another question
- Vote to close as duplicate
- Place the link into the search box
- See the result

Why is this a problem you ask? First, it's confusing when the title and then lower bar say it's duplicate but the header is missing. Second, I can't follow the duplicate-chain to the canonical question from within the close-dialog.

<sub>No questions were closed in the making of this question.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the next build the duplicate notice will show up, as it does on the question page itself.