# Getting "Question eligible for bounty since ..." but where is the location of the “start a bounty” button?

Tags: support, bounties

I'm getting "Question eligible for bounty since ..." on the following Stack Overflow question, but where is the location of the “start a bounty” button?

- [How to open a program by bash script on a workspace = virtual desktop, which is specified by number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210118/how-to-open-a-program-by-bash-script-on-a-workspace-virtual-desktop-which-is)

The following existing answers don't answer my question:

- [Why can't I offer a bounty on my 3 day old question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185127/why-cant-i-offer-a-bounty-on-my-3-day-old-question)
- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Under *"Add a comment"* under the comments

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Under "Add a comment" I find the link "Question eligible for bounty since Jul 3". A I dont know how to start the bounty. I there anything on the linked page ?

Comment: @Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog, I didnt find a hint about where is the "Start bounty button" or a screenshot of this button.

Comment: You have answered that question (even though your answer is deleted), that means you need to offer at least 100 reputation as a bounty.

Comment: @Glorfindel, Which answer is deleted ?

Comment: You have two deleted answers on your own question

Comment: @Tomerikoo, and what are the result of this ?

Comment: @Eddy763 Normally, the minimum amount of rep you can offer as a bounty is 50. But if you have already posted an answer to the question before starting the bounty, the minimum becomes 100. Visit [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for the full list of rules.

Comment: You should really merge your answers by the looks of it and delete one of them as one seems to be an example for the other answer.